# Lambda query needs inferred type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to run some code that I have inherited. It uses lambda expressions to return some invoices and various different calculated values. The code is as below. The problem code is:

```
var queryable = from i in this.db.Invoices
    join j in this.db.JobBooks on i.JobBook_ID equals (int?) j.Job_Book_ID into j
    where (i.Month == month) && (i.Year == year)
    select new { 
        inv = i,
        job = j
    };
return new AccountsTotal { 
    TotalActuals = Queryable.Sum(queryable, i => i.inv.Month_Value),
    TotalForecasts = Queryable.Sum(queryable, i => i.inv.Month_Forecast_Billing),
    TotalCredits = Queryable.Sum(queryable, i => i.inv.Credits),
    TotalInvoiced = Queryable.Sum(from i in queryable
        where (i.inv.Month_Value >= 0M) && ((i.inv.Month_Invoice_Number != null) && (i.inv.Month_Invoice_Number != ""))
        select i, i => i.inv.Month_Value),
    ISActuals =Queryable.Sum(from i in queryable
        where i.job.Business_Unit == 0
        select i, i => i.inv.Month_Value),
    ISForecasts = Queryable.Sum(from i in queryable
        where i.job.Business_Unit == 0
        select i, i => i.inv.Month_Forecast_Billing),
    ISCredits = Queryable.Sum(from i in queryable
        where i.job.Business_Unit == 0
        select i, i => i.inv.Credits),
    ICActuals = Queryable.Sum(from i in queryable
        where i.job.Business_Unit == 1
        select i, i => i.inv.Month_Value),
    ICForecasts = Queryable.Sum(from i in queryable
        where i.job.Business_Unit == 1
        select i, i => i.inv.Month_Forecast_Billing),
    ICCredits = Queryable.Sum(from i in queryable
        where i.job.Business_Unit == 1
        select i, i => i.inv.Credits)
};
```

In the section where it returns the total, all is good until the line that begins "ISActual = Queryable..."

Queryable.Sum has an error, the message for which says the type method for method Queryable.Sum cannot be inferred. And that I should specify the type implicitly. I am not sure where and having tried where it seems logical, they have all failed. It should be a decimal.

The next line [I.job.Business_unit] says that there is no definition for Business_Unit. If I declare a variable at the top of the procedure however of type job, then it recognises the class and the property Business_Unit.

If anyone can help with this, it would be fantastic.

Comment: For us to be able to really help here you need a [mcve].

Comment: Is `ISActuals` a decimal or does it have the type `object`? Either way, you can implicitly add the expected type like this: `ISActuals =Queryable.Sum<decimal>(...`

Comment: Thanks Tom I tried the 'Sum<decimal>' solution before but it didn't work and again after your solution but with no success.Now in my work office, where the same code, without the '<decimal>', is now being accepted, both running framework 4.5, the only difference being home one is in Visual Studio 2012, the work version VS 2015. Both have the latest updates. This is fine for in the current office, but I will ignore the 2012 case for now, 

The problem now then is that the line  [where i.job.Business_Unit == 0]  doesn't see 'job' as an object like it does 'inv', and treats it as an enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems one answer but both problems resolved. I cannot explain why or how the queryable issue was resolved, but it is: I first posted this issue while I was working on VS2012 and Tom your casting solution is one that I had tried and it didn't work, although I think it was right. I then took the code to a machine running VS2015, I tried casting it there with no joy. I then did another clean and rebuild without the cast, and the problem was gone. Came back to 2012 with the code, problem still gone. I cannot explain how or why..

The other problem, the enumerable issue, solved by casting the variable j as the class type job.

```
 select new { 
    inv = i,
    job = (JobBook)j
 };
```

It is strange why invoice didn't need the cast. I guess these things are what comes of creating assemblies from previously compiled assemblies and decompilers. I tried Telerik, ILSpy and finally Reflector. Finally settled on the last. The IT people bods and the previous developer who walked away with all the code need a strong word in their ear...

Thanks guys for your help...